# Getting `Gas estimation failed` for Avalanche quotes

Tags: 0x

I'm currently implementing the Avalanche 0x API for swapping in our UI. The quote arguments are the same as what we use for the ETH mainnet, but it returns `Gas estimation failed`; not sure how to debug this, can someone please help?

Below is an example call we make:

https://avalanche.api.0x.org/swap/v1/quote?&buyToken=0xa7d7079b0fead91f3e65f86e8915cb59c1a4c664&sellToken=0xb31f66aa3c1e785363f0875a1b74e27b85fd66c7&slippagePercentage=0.0025&sellAmount=550000000000000000

```
buyToken: AVAX contract address
sellToken: USDC contract address
takerAddress: the address of the user that is initiating the swap
sellAmount: amount in AVAX
NOTE: we also use affiliateAddress and slippagePercentage but I haven't included them in the link above
```

Thanks!

Comment: I think this refers to the available gas. The function call first estimates if it's been allocated enough gas to accomplish/run the function. If not, it will not run as that would just spend the allocated gas without accomplishing anything.

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens if `takerAddress` does not have the funds or allowances set up to make the trade.